# what type of differential equation is it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

someone can indicate me that type of equation is and its solution method.

$$x^{2}\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+4=0$$

I understand that it performs the second order

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss the final $y$ as in $x^2y''+xy'+4y=0$?

Answer (score 2):

The homogeneous part is an Euler-Cauchy DE, so it is easy to find basis solutions.

For instance by substituting $x=e^t$ to get an equation with constant coefficients.

Or by computing a power series, Frobenius' method.

---

Or you can see that it is a first order ODE with the usual solution formula after substituting $u=y'$.

---

Or you can combine the terms to the easily integrable form $$x(xy')'=-4$$

Comment: If you and wikipedia say so, adapted. I've seen inhomogeneous examples with polynomial right sides or polynomial-logarithm combinations that play well with the transformation to constant coefficients.

Comment: It does not really matter, as the only interesting part about the E-C structure (Cauchy had too many things named after himself) is the homogeneous equation. With the basis solutions found the usual variation of constants apparatus can be set to work, as for any other linear DE.

Answer (score 0):

It is a second order homogeneous differential equation with non-constant coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$\frac{d^2y(x)}{d^2x}=\frac{dv(x)}{dx}$$
and $$\mu(x)=e^{\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=x$$ we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(xv(x)\right)=-\frac{4}{x}$$
Can you finish?